# Delete All Files in a Directory Except One on every sunday 20 hour

Tags: boot, command-line, 20.04, scripts

I use this option

In autodelete.sh

```
rm -rf /home/user/Public/!("VIP Folder")
```

In Crontab

```
0 20 * * 0 /home/autodelete.sh
```

but it is does not work.

Answer (score 4):

The `!(pattern)` syntax is part of the extended globbing capabilities of bash and this isn't on by default. You need to make sure that your script is using `bash` and not `sh`, and you need to enable the relevant option. So make your `autodelete.sh` file look like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob
rm -rf /home/user/Public/!("VIP Folder")
```

The quotes are optional in this case, but don't hurt either and are a good habit to have.

Also, your crontab line will run this command every day at 20:00 and not every Sunday only. To run it at 20:00 on Sundays, use:

```
0 20 * * 0 /home/autodelete.sh
```

Comment: Good point, @steeldriver, thanks.

Comment: Thank u so much it work, @steeldriver